# Is there a way to read one CSV data set from a tar.gz with many data sets in R language?

Tags: r, dataset, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unzip a tar.gz file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151145/unzip-a-tar-gz-file-in-r)

I have a tar.gz file which contains a set of CSV files in it. How do I read only one file into R data frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the filename of the file in the archive you want then you can specify that it be extracted and then read as per usual. E.g.

```
untar("foo.tar.gz", files = "foo2.csv")
```

will extract the file `foo2.csv` from the archive `foo.tar.gz` into the current working/local directory. You can then load that CSV in the usual way

```
read.csv("foo2.csv")
```

If you don't know the filenames, list them first:

```
> untar("foo.tar.gz", list = TRUE)
[1] "foo.csv"  "foo2.csv"
```

then extract the one you want.

Comment: I know the question didn't ask it, but `unzip()` does the same thing as `untar()` for `.zip` files.