# Reading data from

Tags: r

I got some info from google on how to read gz file . So I downloaded a file called gdc_download_20191030_052506.304900.tar.gz from https://gdc.cancer.gov/

I am now reading the file in R using this code.

```
> z1 <- gzcon(gzfile("D:/New folder/gdc_download_20191030_052506.304900.tar.gz"))
> z1
A connection with                                                                                                            
description "gzcon(D:/New folder/gdc_download_20191030_052506.304900.tar.gz)"
class       "gzcon"                                                                                         
mode        "rb"                                                                                            
text        "binary"                                                                                        
opened      "closed"                                                                                        
can read    "yes"                                                                                           
can write   "yes"
```

But after this I am not able to see the table here. I think we need to perform other operations as well. Please guide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unzip a tar.gz file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151145/unzip-a-tar-gz-file)

Comment: Thanks. But there is a initial issue. In those solutions, there are data link directly. But  I do not have a data link. I have a website and in the website when I click on download button, the data is downloaded and store in my local drive. I am not able to find the link to the data. Please advice

Comment: can't you use the local link/path to your .tar.gz file?

Comment: I tried. But not working for example ````fn1 <- "D:/New Folder/gdc_download_20191030_052506.304900.tar.gz"```` then ````download.file(fn1,destfile="tmp1.tar.gz")````

Comment: why would you want to download a file that is already on your system?

Comment: Oh. Yeah. Then How do I proceed? You can use the file ````gdc_download_20191030_052506.304900.tar.gz```` to try in your system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201602/discussion-between-wimpel-and-dev-p).